# Discovering the cause of Vim exit status

Tags: vim

On running:

```
vim /tmp/blah
:q
echo $?
```

I get an exit status of `1`. This is breaking various things including Git. If I run vim without my vimrc:

```
vim -u NONE /tmp/blah
:q
echo $?
```

I get an exit status of `0`. I use Pathogen so this also effectively disables plugins. Does anyone have a suggestion for efficiently determining the cause of the exit status? I'm aware of running Vim verbosely and logging to a file. Should I be looking for something specific in this file?

If there is a method of finding the exact line that determines the exit status I would love to know of it as searching around didn't turn much up.

Comment: It would probably help if you posted your .vimrc.

Comment: I'm afraid it probably wouldn't. It's over 2000 lines long and I use around 25 plugins. Bit of a needle in a haystack problem you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found this command in help: `:cq[uit]`. So after you do verbose logging, search for `\<cq\%[uit]\>`.

**Update:** There are also methods to alter the exit status using vim compiled with some interpreters support: at least, the following works:

```
python import sys
python sys.exit(1)
" (same for python3)

perl exit 1
```

I do not know other languages enough to write here examples of code that would quit vim with different exit status. Note also that such commands inside files sourced using `:pyfile`, `:rubyfile` and other `:*file` should also work, as well as this code in a modules not distributed with plugin.

I think the most efficient way here at this point is disabling plugins until you find the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no luck I'm afraid. I thought it might be cquit too and should have written that in my question. It doesn't turn up in the log (with -V15) and isn't in a single file in my .vim/ (including .vimrc). I also searched for 'cq' and scanned every hit to be sure, there are only a dozen or so.

Comment: This prompts the question: what else can modify the exit status?

Comment: Just to come back to this question. I have finally resolved the symptom by upgrading to Vim 7.3. Somewhere a script must have been using a new feature. I never did manage to track it down though. Thanks for your help.