# Vim and syntastic prevent to save git commit message

Tags: git, vim

I have a problem with the git messages and the plugin Syntastics for Vim.

If I try to save a message with the command:

```
git commit -a
```

I always get the error:

```
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

That happens only when I have those line in my .vimrc enabled:

```
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['jshint']
```

If I comment those line I can save my commit messages without any problem.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: For what it's worth, this has nothing to do with Git: Git is just checking the return code from the editor. Somehow your plugin is making vim exit with a failure status (but I don't know how).

Comment: But when I write/save normal files I don' have any problem...
This happens only when I'm writing a git commit message...

Comment: Just because vim exits with "failure status" doesn't mean the files aren't saved. Perhaps writing and saving normal files is "failing" (but actually working) and no one bothers to check, unlike Git which bothers to check. Or perhaps the plugin is mis-classifying Git's commit-message temporary file and making the editor fail because it thinks the temporary file is Java or JavaScript or whatever it is that it checks.

Comment: You don't need syntastic when you write a commit message so… don't use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Discovering the cause of Vim exit status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956001/discovering-the-cause-of-vim-exit-status): look for `cq` and `exit`, make sure Vim is up to date.

Comment: How about adding `gitcommit` to disabled filetypes for syntastic `let g:syntastic_disabled_filetypes=['gitcommit']`